# Show uniformly convergence

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> > I would like to show, that $\frac{f(h,x)-f(0,x)}{h}\to \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(t,x)\right|_{t=0}$ converges uniformly for $h\to 0$ on a compact set $K$.

The tutor gave the hint to use the Mean Value theorem and the compactness of $K$.

Could you please help me? I do not come along with this proof.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Is the partial derivative continuous ?

Comment: Yes it is continious in x.

Answer (score 0):

For want of a complete statement, I try.

If compactness is assumed, continuity implies uniform continuity.

Suppose that, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ **independent on $x$** such that $|f_x(t,x)-f_x(0,x)|<\varepsilon\,$ if $\,|t|<\delta$.

By the MVT, one has $$\frac {f(h,x)-f(0,x)}h=f_x(c_x,x)$$with $\,0<|c_x|<|h|$ .

If you take $h$ such that $|h|<\delta$, you are done.